# Custom query shows custom post types in trash

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, query-posts

I have a custom wordpress query like so:

```
$query = new WP_Query(array(
  'post_status' => 'future || publish', 
  'post_type' => 'kalender', 
  'order' => 'ASC'
));
```

But the problem is that the items shown on the pages also include the items that are in the trash? I don't understand why because according to the `post_status` only published & future posts should be shown?

The item in the trash is a post in the future though? Maybe that's why it's shown but how can I exclude that one?

Comment: I assume you're trying to create an event calendar of sorts by using the publish date as the event date. if that's the case, you're better off storing the event date as post meta data rather than abusing the publish date for this purpose.

Comment: @Milo Thank you for your suggestion, I understand your reasoning, I'll change it soon!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The syntax in the query above is wrong, it should be:

```
$query = new WP_Query(array(
  'post_status' => array( 'publish', 'future' ),
  'post_type' => 'kalender',
  'order' => 'ASC'
));
```

That seems to solve the problem. :)